# How to put formula and its variables side to side?

Tags: lists, arrows, formulas

[image: My goal : the formula and its variables at its right]

I want to write a formula and put on its right side the description of its variables. Here I just screenshoted the two parts and put them side to side with figure environment but I want to write some "code" that puts it like that but not with screenshots or pictures or anything like that. Is it possible ? And if yes, how can I do that ?

Comment: Two minipages center [c] aligned woudl be easiest.  Ste the width to `{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.6\columnsep}` and use `\hfill` to separate them (do **not** add a blank line) between them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it with `itemize` and `varwidth`, so you don't have to guess the width for the `enumerate`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % required for French in pdflatex
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\frenchsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}

\begin{document}

\[
\overrightarrow{E(M)}=\frac{kq}{r^2}\times\vec{u}_r
\quad
\begin{varwidth}{\displaywidth}
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item $k$: constante de Coulomb
\item $q$: valeur de la charge
\item $r$: distance
\item $\vec{u}_r$: vecteur directeur
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's a bit more difficult if you want the two parts top aligned.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % required for French in pdflatex
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\frenchsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}

\begin{document}

\[
\raisebox{-\height}{$\displaystyle
  \overrightarrow{E(M)}=\frac{kq}{r^2}\times\vec{u}_r
$}
\quad
\raisebox{-\height}{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\displaywidth}
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item $k$: constante de Coulomb
  \item $q$: valeur de la charge
  \item $r$: distance
  \item $\vec{u}_r$: vecteur directeur
  \end{itemize}
  \end{varwidth}%
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would not hardcode the bullets, so the style of the `itemize` is consistent with the rest of the document. For instance, if you remove the `\frenchsetup` line, you get, for the second example,

[image]

which, according to the maintainers of `babel-french` should be the common way for first level itemized lists.

Comment: Thank you, I looked for the second way to make that. I didn't know what was varwidth package. I'll investigate.
But what does mean \quad ?

Comment: @Amnezic `\quad` is a horizontal space of width 1em (basically, the width of M), a traditional typographic device.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways to produce the same output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

%% Method 1
\begin{center}
$\displaystyle \overrightarrow{E(M)}=\frac{kq}{r^2}\times\vec{u}_r$%
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{>{\textbullet\space}l}
$k$: constante de Coulomb \\
$q$: valeur de la charge\\
$r$: distance\\
$\vec{u}_r$: vecteur directeur
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

%% Method 2
\[ 
\overrightarrow{E(M)}=\frac{kq}{r^2}\times\vec{u}_r
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{>{\textbullet\space}l}
  $k$: constante de Coulomb \\
  $q$: valeur de la charge\\
  $r$: distance\\
  $\vec{u}_r$: vecteur directeur
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```